# Font and Alignment Issues

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need a little assistance with a couple of things.

1) Please click
[here](http://annaswardrobe.net/deal_site/)

There you will see a Subscribe Now Box. I want this box to move up on the Navigation Bar just beside that Contact Link. But when I move it up, it goes behind that navigation bar and hides itself behind it. I have tried

```
 margin-top:-60px;
```

then

```
position:relative;
top:-60px;
```

None of the both work. Kindly tell me how can I move it up without getting it behind the navigation bar?

Second thing is that you may note that the font of the website looks all torned. How can I fix it? The font that was used in PSD was "Tw Cen MT" but it looks no where near in the web.

Please guide. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ahmad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS, then you can move it up with `position:relative; top:-60px;`

```
#search-subscribe-area .content-area {
    overflow: inherit;
}
```

The font is your CSS is 'Source Sans Pro';
Try to use Fonts made for the Web

https://www.google.com/fonts

Here you can go and browse for the fonts you like, and tell the designer he should look for fonts there, you can imprt then to your Website using css and you can download it via .zip so the designer can use the same Font in Photoshop as you see it in the Web